# Create promised function to sort by name and then chain it

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, promise

Create another promisified function that sorts this employee list from below response by name. Chain it to below promise

```
function arr() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            resolve(employeeDetailsArray);
        }, 2000);
    });
}

arr()
.then(function(result) {
    console.log(result); 
    return arr();
})
.then() ////code to sort by name, output should be sorted list of employee details by name

const employeeDetailsArray = [
  { name: 'boss', email: 'boss@gmail.com', age: 22 },
  { name: 'avid', email: 'avid@gmail.com', age: 60 },
  { name: 'rajam', email: 'rajam@gmail.com', age: 75 },
  { name: 'dam', email: 'dam@gmail.com', age: 45 }
]
```

output should be :-

//after 2 seconds(this is done)

```
       const employeeDetailsArray = [
      { name: 'boss', email: 'boss@gmail.com', age: 22 },
      { name: 'avid', email: 'avid@gmail.com', age: 60 },
      { name: 'rajam', email: 'rajam@gmail.com', age: 75 },
      { name: 'dam', email: 'dam@gmail.com', age: 45 }
    ]
```

//then it should print same array in sorted order by name(this is remaining)

```
    const employeeDetailsArray = [
      { name: 'avid', email: 'avid@gmail.com', age: 60 },
      { name: 'boss', email: 'boss@gmail.com', age: 22 },
      { name: 'dam', email: 'dam@gmail.com', age: 45 }, 
      { name: 'rajam', email: 'rajam@gmail.com', age: 75 },
      ]
```

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear, could you give a more clear explanation of what you want to achieve? For example, give an example input and output table with the desired results. 

Please make sure to read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask good questions, so we can help you better!

Comment: @TristanT. now cheak my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, you could write a new function `sortByName(array)` like this:

```js
function sortByName(array) {
  return array.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.name < b.name) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (a.name > b.name) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  });
}
```

This sorts the array by name. This could also be minimized to:

```js
function sortByName(array) {
  return array.sort((a, b) => {
    return a.name > b.name ? 1 : -1;
  });
}
```

With the same functionality in this case.

You could then call it using:

```js
arr().then(function(result) {
  console.log(result);
}).then(function (result) {
  console.log(sortByName(result));
})
```

This should achieve your desired result.
**Why does this work?**

You can chain `.then()` and `.catch()` multiple times. The code blocks will execute one after another. Please also keep in mind that returning something from `.then(function(data))` could have undesired effects, as `.then()` returns a promise and not the data itself directly. Please read more about it at [this article](https://javascript.info/promise-chaining).